# Error while getting latitude and longitude using lastknown location from gps provider and network provider in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

I want to get the last known location from network provider as well as gps provider. So I have written the following code in my java application.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
public class Map extends Activity implements LocationListener{

private GoogleMap googleMap;
  // Update frequency in seconds
public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;
// Define an object that holds accuracy and frequency parameters
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
LocationClient mLocationClient;
boolean mUpdatesRequested;
double clat,clong,gpslat,gpslong,netlat,netlong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Location gps,network;
    LocationManager locationmanager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationlistener=new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);


    gps=locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    network=locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    Double gpslat,gpslong,netlat,netlong;
    gpslat=gps.getLatitude();
    gpslong=gps.getLongitude();
    netlat=network.getLatitude();
    netlong=network.getLongitude();

    /*MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(gpslat, gpslong)).title("Gps location ");
    MarkerOptions marker1=new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(netlat, netlong)).title("Network Location");
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    googleMap.addMarker(marker1);*/

    // create marker
    //MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");


    // adding marker
    //googleMap.addMarker(marker);

    //CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
     //       new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(15).build();

//googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

But the application force closes and shows error like this in logcat:

```
09-20 12:05:14.350: I/Google Maps Android API(12062): Google Play services client version: 5089000
09-20 12:05:14.350: I/dalvikvm(12062): Could not find method gui.a, referenced from method gqh.a
09-20 12:05:14.350: W/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: unable to resolve static method 24934: Lgui;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgrh;
09-20 12:05:14.350: D/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
09-20 12:05:14.360: E/dalvikvm(12062): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-20 12:05:14.360: W/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
09-20 12:05:14.360: D/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
09-20 12:05:14.360: E/dalvikvm(12062): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-20 12:05:14.360: W/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
09-20 12:05:14.360: D/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
09-20 12:05:14.360: E/dalvikvm(12062): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-20 12:05:14.360: W/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
09-20 12:05:14.360: D/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
09-20 12:05:14.360: D/dalvikvm(12062): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0a in Lgpr;.a
09-20 12:05:14.360: D/dalvikvm(12062): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0c in Lgpr;.a
09-20 12:05:14.360: D/dalvikvm(12062): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0a in Lgpr;.a
09-20 12:05:14.370: I/Google Maps Android API(12062): Google Play services package version: 5089070
09-20 12:05:14.380: W/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
09-20 12:05:14.380: D/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
09-20 12:05:14.390: W/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
09-20 12:05:14.390: D/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
09-20 12:05:14.550: I/dalvikvm(12062): JIT_INFO: Unresolved fieldPtr at sget_sput_common
09-20 12:05:14.550: I/dalvikvm(12062): Could not compile trace for Lohs;<clinit>, offset 9
09-20 12:05:14.550: D/dalvikvm(12062): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
09-20 12:05:14.550: D/dalvikvm(12062): JIT_INFO: Issues while compiling trace  Lohs;<clinit>, offset 9
09-20 12:05:14.550: D/dalvikvm(12062):  Trace contains SGET / SPUT bytecode with unresolved field.
09-20 12:05:14.550: D/dalvikvm(12062): JIT_INFO: Terminating trace due to unresolved issues
09-20 12:05:14.550: D/dalvikvm(12062): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
09-20 12:05:14.560: W/ActivityThread(12062): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
09-20 12:05:14.590: I/dalvikvm(12062): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lglm;'
09-20 12:05:14.590: W/dalvikvm(12062): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
09-20 12:05:14.590: E/dalvikvm(12062): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
09-20 12:05:14.590: W/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lgls;
09-20 12:05:14.590: D/dalvikvm(12062): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0019
09-20 12:05:14.700: D/dalvikvm(12062): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5073K, 37% free 9468K/14820K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
09-20 12:05:14.720: D/AndroidRuntime(12062): Shutting down VM
09-20 12:05:14.720: W/dalvikvm(12062): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42ede500)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.barcodescanner/com.example.barcodescanner.Map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2300)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:744)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at com.example.barcodescanner.Map.onCreate(Map.java:77)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5288)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2214)
09-20 12:05:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(12062):    ... 11 more
```

Can some one please help me what the error is and correct me if I'm wrong. All want is to get latitude and longitude using getlastknown location from gps provider and network provider and display it in google maps and mark it using a marker.

This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: From `onResume()` method just remove the line `initilizeMap();` and then try to run your code. Also you have already implemented `LocationListener` interface in your class so there is no need to implement it again in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: still the error is there..:(

Comment: Please tell me what is your line no: 77 ?

Comment: line 77 @ this : netlat=network.getLatitude();

Comment: Sorry @ this sentence line 77: gpslat=gps.getLatitude();

Comment: first check the gps  null or not.

Comment: how do I check that??

Comment: Have you provided sufficient permissions in your manifest?

Comment: yes. check this out:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />